# How to make Photoshop CS6 render a 2D text into 3D?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, 3d

I have a 2D logo that I would like to render 3D using Photoshop CS6.

I have gone as far as using new 3D extrusion from current selection.

However, once the 3D shadow is made, it looks black. I'd like it to match the original color from the logo.

**How can I create a 3D extrusion within Photoshop CS6 and assign a custom color to shadows?**

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily fix that by changing the texture assigned to the material which is assigned to the 3d extrusion. I would recommend you to sperate the logo into parts which have different colors so that you can have different textures and materials for each letter or design in the logo. which will allow you to give different colors to different areas.

But if you have a vector file of the logo I would suggest you try illustrators 3d option first.